# Can adjuncts modify nouns?

Tags: syntax, grammar, adjuncts, constituents

The [Wikipedia page on adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)) gives the example

> **Yesterday**, Lorna saw the dog **in the garden**.
>
> Notice that this example is ambiguous between whether the adjunct in the garden modifies the
> verb saw (in which case it is Lorna who saw the dog while she was in
> the garden) or the noun phrase the dog (in which case it is the dog
> who is in the garden). The definition can be extended to include
> adjuncts that modify nouns or other parts of speech (see [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)).

The page on noun adjunct says (emphasis mine)

> a noun adjunct ... is an optional **noun** that modifies another noun

Seems to be only about using nouns like adjectives, so actually "in the garden" doesn't seem to be a noun adjunct at all.

Can adjuncts ever modify nouns? What is the correct term for the parallel to adjuncts regarding nouns/noun phrases? E.g. could "on the plate" in

> The sauce **on the plate** was eaten by him

Have any name in addition to prepositional phrase?

Comment: In “The sauce on the plate”, _on the plate_ is an **attributive phrase**. I'm not sure about English with its strict and too-meaningful word order, but in Slavic languages such phrases as “very fool” or “drug addict for a long time” are quite valid. Anyhow, every English sentence needs a verb, so if there's any adjunct in your sentence, you're going to have hard time proving the adjunct modifies _not_ the verb.

Comment: @YellowSky why is it an attributive phrase and not a prepositional phrase?

Comment: It is an attributive prepositional phrase. It is prepositional by form and attributive by meaning/function.

Comment: Note that _noun adjunct_ does not mean ‘adjunct that modifies a noun’. An adjunct that modifies a noun is an **adnominal adjunct**, but adnominal adjuncts can be of any form allowed (adjectives, for example). Rather, a noun adjunct is specifically an adjunct _which is itself a noun_. Since nouns on their own can only modify other nouns, a noun adjunct (= adjunct which _is_ a noun) will always also be an adnominal adjunct (= adjunct which _modifies_ a noun), but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common meaning of "adjunct" on its own is as "adverbial adjunct".

So the Wikipedia page spends most of its time talking about adverbial adjuncts and even acknowledges this:

> Most discussions of adjuncts focus on adverbial adjuncts, that is, on adjuncts that modify verbs, verb phrases, or entire clauses

But you can have non-adverbial adjuncts.

> Adjuncts can appear in other domains, however; that is, they can modify most categories.

An adjunct that modifies a noun, as in your example, is called an **adnominal adjunct**.